# How to tell the cache_page decorator to use different cache_keys with regards to the Accept header?

Tags: django

I realized that the cache_page decorator will cache text/html or application/json responses and return one for the other without noticing.

I'd like to  give cache_page a list of header to use to generate a cache key so that it can take it into account.

Answer (score 1):

I guess https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers is probably what I am looking for.

`@vary_on_headers('Accept')`